# '' which '' refers to what?

Tags: grammar

in this sentence '' which '' refers to what ?

> Reconstruction of "Orange Socks", created prior to her official 2019 identification, which estimated how she may have looked when she was alive

Comment: More context would help. It appears that this refers to a murder victim who was only identified 40 years after being found. Commonsense suggests that 'which' refers to the reconstruction, though this isn't clear from the grammar.

Comment: I agree it refers to the reconstruction, though I think it is clear, if it's the caption of a photograph.

Comment: I concur with Kate and Jack. Just read the sentence without the bit between the commas which are being used instead of parenthesis to add further, but not essential, information (you see what I did there?)

Comment: The antecedent for "which" is the NP "reconstruction of "Orange Socks". Btw, it's not a sentence but an NP.